# Security of a simple AEAD construction

Tags: authenticated-encryption, ctr, cbc-mac, speck

### Introduction

I want securely communicate with a small 8-bit device which has a very limited program program memory (Arduino Uno - 32K).

My goal is to minimize code size and RAM usage. There are multiple alternatives I could use, but I have reasons to believe that all of them would have larger code size and/or RAM usage. See the end of this post for details.

I came up with a very simple Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data (AEAD) construction that uses the Speck block cipher. Any block cipher with a 128-bit block size could be used, but Speck is super small in software.

Speck is used both for authentication (CBC-MAC) and encryption (CTR mode). In both cases, I'm using a 128-bit block size and a 128-bit key size.

### High-level overview

Like proper AEAD modes, this construction offers two operations:

- authenticated encryption
- authenticated decryption

I'm going for an interface similar to what NaCl does, except I include additional authentication-only data, and I use two separate keys. The authenticated encryption operation thus takes five inputs:

- authentication key  $K_A$
- encryption key $K_E$
- nonce $N$
- plaintext $P$
- associated data $A$

Output is ciphertext $C$, which contains everything needed to reconstruct $N$, $P$ and $A$. If you know the keys, that is.

Interface for authenticated decryption simply takes this ciphertext $C$ and returns true if MAC verification and all other integrity checks succeed; otherwise, it returns false.  It also returns $N$, $P$ and $A$.

### Authenticated encryption

Since I'm going for extreme simplicity and small code size, I made this construction quite inflexible and limited:

- nonce $N$ must be exactly $7$ bytes
- additional data $A$ must be exactly $8$ bytes
- plaintext $P$ must be a multiple of $16$ bytes

Byte $0$ of the output $C$ is the number of blocks in $P$ ($\frac{length}{16}$). The purpose of this is to make the set of all messages prefix-free for [use in CBC-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27925/32915). It also limits the maximum message size to $256 \times 16 = 4$ kilobytes.

Bytes $1-7$ of $C$ are the nonce $N$.

Bytes $8-15$ of $C$ are the additional authenticated data $A$.

Next comes $P$ encrypted in CTR mode with the $K_E$. Counter blocks are constructed as follows:

- $7$ bytes nonce $N$
- $8$ bytes zeroes
- $1$ byte counter

Lastly, CBC-MAC is calculated by encrypting *all* previous $C$ data in CBC mode with the authentication key $K_A$ and a [zero IV](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/02/why-i-hate-cbc-mac.html) (check out point no. 2). The last block of this encryption is appended to $C$.

I believe this scheme could be described as [Encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac).

I am intentionally refraining from using all bytes of the counter block to limit the number of blocks encrypted by a single key. The user will be advised to not use the upper $4$ bits of the nonce to limit encryption to $2^{60}$ blocks, which is the maximum recommended for CTR mode by Ferguson and Schneier in Cryptography Engineering.

### Questions

1. Assuming the nonce $N$ is unique for each message, does this construction meet the standard notions of confidentiality and authenticity?
2. Is it accurate to call this an AEAD construction, or would another name be more preferable?

### Alternatives

I could use AVRNaCl, but their procedure for verifying and decrypting a ciphertext (`crypto_secretbox_open`) compiles to about 6K, whereas the crypto described in this question is less than 2.5K, and could probably be optimized down to 2K.

I could also use CCM or EAX with something like AES or Speck, but I believe this would also have a larger compiled code, and here's my argument:

1. According to JP Norair, [EAX needs less code than CCM](http://www.indigresso.com/_blog/?p=106).
2. There's a really nice set of libraries for the Arduino called ArduinoLibs, and it contains a [cryptographic library](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/crypto.html) which includes Speck and EAX. I tried compiling EAX with SpeckTiny, and the code size was more than 4K.
3. If EAX has smaller code size than CCM, then it won't be less than the 4K for EAX. Unless, of course, the EAX code is optimized, but I'm not an expert in AVR assembly, and I'm still not sure it would come close to the size of the construction described in this post.
4. Even just intuitively, the construction described in this post is simple. It's a few lines of simple code. The only challenge with implementation that I found is to make a constant-time MAC verification. Both CCM and EAX are more complex than this.

Comment: Is there a reason you do home-brewn CTR+CBC-MAC over proper [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) (or even [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode))?

Comment: I'm not surprised that you were able to get something based on SPECK into a smaller footprint than xsalsa20/poly1305, but I'm surprised by it being a factor of 3. Have you looked at the compiled output of AVRNaCl to see if there's anything that can be stripped out?

Comment: Well, I think both CCM and EAX would have larger code sizes and perhaps RAM usage. I haven't tried implementing them, but I have checked out [Brian Gladman's code](https://github.com/BrianGladman/modes) for these modes (ccm.c and eax.c), and it doesn't look very small.

Comment: As far as AVRNaCl is concerned, they have multiple versions. I have tried the version which is supposed to be the smallest. It uses lots of assembly code, so I haven't tried optimizing it.

Comment: nit-pick: most formal specifications output $(N||A||C||\tau))$ and return either $\perp$ or $P$ upon input of $(N||A||C||\tau)$.

Comment: So based on nonce/counter sizes, I assume there is no need for more than 4KB of data per message, and you will be encrypting many trillions of messages?

Comment: @RichieFrame, see the earlier versions of the question for the nonce construction. TL;DR: The OP wants to do file transfer and and composes a part the nonce from a unique file ID and from a file block ID where the only potential issue would be time-based nonce re-use (e.g. you request the same file segment twice, before and after a change and thus the nonce will (likely)  repeat). @ Roman, this is an AEAD construction because it does authenticated encryption and accepts associated data.

Comment: Note that you could also use Speck in CCM mode

Comment: @Demetri Thank you, but I know. I edited my post to explain why I'm not using it.

Comment: You ought to store (a part of) the nonce in nonvolitile memory and do the write synchronously before each encryption.

Comment: @Demetri I don't think power outages will be an issue. See revision 4 of this question for an idea of how I plan to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, this is secure.**

(one of the few cases where I'm pretty confident about this).

Here are the arguments:

- Combining a secure (e.g. SUF-CMA) MAC with a secure (e.g. CPA-secure) encryption method in encrypt-then-authenticate is generally proven secure. This was shown in ["Authenticated Encryption: Relations among notions and analysis of the generic composition paradigm" by M. Bellare and C. Namprempre (PDF)](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/oem.pdf). Also worth a read is [the answer by Yehuda Lindell](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26638/23623) on the linked question, which emphasizes the fact **that you should use established modes (like [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) or [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode)) if possible**, as they already come with a full proof of security.
- Your're using CBC-MAC with a prepended message length which was shown to be a secure MAC by Rackoff and Gorbunov in ["On the Security of Cipher Block Chaining Message Authentication Code" (PDF)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~sgorbuno/publications/securityOfCBC.pdf), assuming the underlying block cipher is a PRF (from which it is indistinguishable up to $2^{n/2}$ blocks with $n$ being the block size in bits)
- The cipher being used is CTR-mode with speck which is a provably (CPA) secure stream cipher if the block cipher can be modeled as a PRF which it can up to $2^{n/2}$ blocks without any problems, furthermore you successfully deployed counter measures against nonce re-use in the underlying mode and thereby should be fine.